# htaccess and two post parameters

Tags: php, css, model-view-controller, .htaccess, post

I developed a small custom MVC framework for my website. it's index.php check $_POST['page'] & $_POST['subpage'] and includes related php file for specified parameter.

Ex: **index.php?page=foods** *(this includes view/foods.php)*

Ex: **index.php?page=foods&subpage=pizza** *(this includes view/foods/pizza.php)*

Now I want to clean my URLS using .htaccess. I tried few methods to pass second parameter. But I failed. This works fine...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But when i tried to pass second parameter its not working fine. This one change css/js/iamges path.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the QSA (Query String Apend) flag, you can simply pass the entire request string to an index file -

> **QSA** - Appends any query string from the original request URL to any query string created in the rewrite target

So your rule would look similar to this -

```
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In your index file you can `.explode()` by slashes -

```
$splitArr = explode('/',$_GET['uri']);
```

And/or use the built in `parse_url()` function - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

> `parse_url` — Parse a URL and return its components

Comment: I tried this one. But it returns Error 500 on Localhost. anything wrong in htacess ?

Comment: Yes. I removed htacess comments and working fine. but i echo $_GET['uri'], that returns just only index.php. Do i need to change anything to pass second parameter?

Comment: But this exclude files/directories that actually exist. What can we do for that ? URL are working fine. One and only problem is CSS, JS & Images.

Comment: that is what's supposed to happen - you want all your urls to resources, that means images, stylesheets and scripts to be given directly and only your nice friendly urls get rewritten...

Comment: Yes. because when i use include() in index.php it exclude every images/css/js etc...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what the problem is... can you  explain whats going wrong?

Comment: I want to do something like this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(js|css|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|ico)$ [NC]` with `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]` but its not working. 

In brief I want to give direct access to all files, and want to catch 2 parameters using this `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: The two lines of code with `REQUEST_FILENAME` do exactly that.  They will ignore actual files (like the ones you listed) - only "fake" URL's that don't point to an actual file will be redirected to your index.php with the path in the parameters...

Answer (score 2):

Most url-rewriters of this type explicitly exclude files/directories that actually exist:

```
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteRule ^public/(js|css|images)(/.*|$) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is how finally I've done it !!!