# htaccess optional parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a very simple rewrite rule. I would like the second parameter in the URL to be optional, but as it stands at the moment i have to pass it in the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^signup/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /signup/index.php?e=$1&s=$2 [L]
```

I have the URL /signup/PARAMETER/OPTIONAL-PARAMETER/

How can I make the url work if I leave the second parameter off?

Joe

Comment: A good example for that was posted in stackoverflow.com at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617183/htacess-and-two-post-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Just add a single parameter rewrite after it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^signup/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /signup/index.php?e=$1&s=$2 [L]

# single parameter
RewriteRule ^signup/([^/]*)/$ /signup/index.php?e=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer from this question [htacess and two post parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617183/htacess-and-two-post-parameters) .... Thanks aeshabana for the tip!

I also needed to add a slash to the URLS so here is my final .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^signup/(.+)/$ /signup/index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```